# Get/Set the account under which WCF service is hosted

Tags: wcf

I am hosting my WCF service in a console application. I need to know -

1. How can I find out under which account and its details this service is hosted?
2. How can I set the account under which the service must be hosted (this is possible in windows service, but how can this be done in a console application?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The current user can be found using:

   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
2. There is an interesting impersonation library on github and available via NuGet that should do the trick:
   [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation)